# Databricks repos notebook deleted by mistake (not commited, not versioned), is posible to restore it?

Tags: databricks, databricks-repos

Accidentally i deleted a notebook from my databricks repo before any commit, I expected to restore it from trash folder but the notebook is not there. Is posible to restore from any directory on the server or something like that?

Comment: is it ok to pull from latest in repo? or you made some changes in it before deletion?

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the repo it should show the following context_menu:

[image: context menu].

Clicking on git will lead you to your latest changes, making it possible to revert uncommitted changes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Getting into the git menu shows me the uncommitted changes but only between my actual state (deleted notebook) and the last version on branch, so the deleted notebook isn't there. I noticed that when you delete a notebook on repo displays an advertise telling that this cannot be undone, but I still wonder if somehow it can be restored.

Answer (score 0):

It was never versioned. I just had created a notebook then deleted it by mistake so it was never anywhere but my repo workspace. Once I deleted the notebook I was hoping to find it in my trash folder, but aparently there is no way no restore it.